# How to get the element of Id based on class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get the Id of a div tag based on class div name?

```js
 function AddActionTableRow() {
        actionTableRowCount++;
        actionItemRowDictionary[actionTableRowCount] = true;
        var rowHtml = "<tr class='actionTableRow actionTableRow" + actionTableRowCount + "'>   <td class='actionTableField' id='actionTableField1'>" + actionTableRowCount + "</td> <td class='actionTableField' id='hiddenActionTableField'>" + 0 + "</td>   <td><input class='actionTableField' id='actionTableField2' type='text'/></td>      <td><select onchange='this.className=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className' class='actionTableField' id='actionTableField3'>    <option value='  --Select--  ' selected disabled>  --Select--  </option>    <option class='blue' value='Category-1'>Category-1</option>     <option class='green' value='In Progress'>Category-2</option>     <option class='yellow' value='Minor Risk'>Category-3</option>     <option class='red' value='Major Risk'>Category-4</option>     </select></td>      <td><select onchange='this.className=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className' class='actionTableField' id='actionTableField4'>    <option value='--select--' selected disabled>  --Select--  </option>    <option class='blue' value='Completed'>Category-1</option>     <option class='green' value='In Progress'>Category-2</option>     <option class='yellow' value='Minor Risk'>Category-3</option>     <option class='red' value='Major Risk'>Category-4</option>     </select></td>      <td><input class='actionTableField' id='actionTableField5' type='text'/></td>    <td><input class='actionTableField' id='actionTableField6' type='text'/></td>  <td><input class='actionTableField' id='actionTableField7' type='text'/></td>   <td><input type='text' id='actionTableField8' class='actionTableField' /></td>   <td><button onclick='DeleteActionItemRow(this)'  class=' actionTableField actionItemDelete actionItemDelete-" + actionTableRowCount + "  '><i class='fa fa-trash-o' style='border-radius:.30rem'   ></i></button></td> </tr>";
        $("#actionTableFoot").append(rowHtml);
        var className = ".actionTableRow" + actionTableRowCount + " #actionTableField2";
        alert(className);
        $(className).focus();
        alert("wdfs");;
        var picker = new Lightpick({

            //field: document.getElementById('actionTableField8'),
            //field: document.getElementsByClassName('actionTableRow actionTableRow' + actionTableRowCount).getElementById('actionTableField8'),
            
            singleDate: false,

            onSelect: function (start, end) {
                var str = '';
                str += start ? start.format('Do MMMM YYYY') + ' to ' : '';
                str += end ? end.format('Do MMMM YYYY') : '...';
                document.getElementById('actionTableField8').innerHTML = str;
                
              
            }
        });
    }
```

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Comment: Do you accept `jQuery` solutions? or did you add the jQuery tag by mistake?

Comment: Jquery is fine .I'll accept the jquery solutions

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to get - bar or f1.   `$(".f1>#bar")` seems pointless - if you already know the ID then just use that as ID's are unique.  *Looks* like you want `$("#bar").closest(".f1")` (ie the parent by class).

Comment: in my case i want to get id based on class name...id will be static and Class name will incremental value appended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to get id of an element from class name,
you can achive it by,

```
<div id="testId" class="testClass"></div>
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($('.testClass').attr('id'));
});
```

But keep in mind class could be used at multiple places, so if you want id of all elements with same class name, you can

```
var retval = []
$('selector').each(function(){
  retval.push($(this).attr('id'))
})
return retval
```

or using map

```
return $('.selector').map(function(index,dom){return dom.id})
```